# How to change the python installation location for Python interpreter in Zeppelin?

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

Where is the python installation location specified for Python interpreter in Zeppelin?

How to change the python installation location for Python interpreter with new python installation directory in Zeppelin?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It worked.

I have set "zeppelin.python" as /mnt/reference/softwares/anaconda27/bin/python in %python interpreter section.